# How do I work with multiple Comboxes in an ASP .NET Core MVC Form?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP .NET Core MVC web page that shows the names of jurors within a panel. The number of panels or jurors aren't fixed, so basically I build the view by looping through the available panels and then by looping through the available jurors:

```
@foreach (var panel in Model.PanelComposition)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <p class="font-weight-bold">@panel.Functie:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            @panel.JuryName
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

For every juror, I display his/her function and full name.

The next step would be to create an edit page for the same data, the idea being to offer a listing of all available jurors through combo boxes. But, I would then have to create a combo box for each available function and post the data back to the controller so I can save the data.

I'm basically wondering how I would do this in a safe & elegant fashion?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want a combobox for function  and a combobox for JuryName?If so,here is a demo:
Models:

```
public class TestComboBoxModel {
        public List<Panel> PanelComposition { get; set; }
    }
    public class Panel {
        public string Functie { get; set; }
        public string JuryName { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult TestComboBox()
        {
            TestComboBoxModel t = new TestComboBoxModel
            {
                PanelComposition = new List<Panel>
                {
                    new Panel
                    {
                         Functie="f1",
                         JuryName="j1"
                    },
                    new Panel
                    {
                         Functie="f2",
                         JuryName="j3"
                    },
                    new Panel
                    {
                         Functie="f3",
                         JuryName="j3"
                    }
                }
            };
            return View(t);
        }
```

TestComboBox.cshtml:

```
<select class="browser-default custom-select">
        @foreach (var panel in Model.PanelComposition)
        {
        <option value=@panel.Functie>@panel.Functie</option>
        }
    </select>
    <select class="browser-default custom-select">
        @foreach (var panel in Model.PanelComposition)
        {
            <option value=@panel.JuryName>@panel.JuryName</option>
        }
    </select>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-combobox/1.2.0/css/bootstrap-combobox.css" integrity="sha512-tuLhxCtoSmZfoZZzq5YIcRz1a1HyDmGrou28T7RWcSJk8cNIHoykHXMQgXVGfKR/CdpESkh4euy7m6EywWzmXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-combobox/1.2.0/js/bootstrap-combobox.js" integrity="sha512-4SfeWbBC4xVSl8Wc/j3/bvg/fX782BUNHO6fuamkk95xakeAvlup1+lefOfgpgsd90KHKBAfPEWtSOYRAMrAzA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

result:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Almost. I don't need to add a combo box  for the functions, those are fixed. Everything is based on a template, which says how many functions exist for each panel. My page serves to select jurors for each of the functions. So I would have a page with for example 5 panels, each panel has 10 functions. You select which panel you edit and you can then change  that panel. In this example I would have 10 combo boxes.